# onLeave react router do not navigate away if

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm creating a data fill in page, and I want to ask users to confirm that they want to leave the page. I see that react router provides an onLeave function with no arguments, but I don't see how to use it in the way I need.

Thanks

Comment: Could you give code which you have tried so far ?

Comment: I have not tried anything. I don't really know how to intercept the router before it changes pages

Comment: There is an example how to handle the Confirming Navigation : https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/v1.0.0-rc4/docs/guides/advanced/ConfirmingNavigation.md

Comment: Wow, that looks perfect. Thanks!